# Как сделать SQL запрос (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

Ситуация следующая, в БД есть 2 таблицы:

1. master (id, name)
2. employee (id, name)

Я хочу построить 1 SELECT запрос на выборку данных.

Делаю запрос (обьединяю столбцы из 2 табл. в один столбец):

```
SELECT master.name
FROM master
UNION ALL
SELECT employee.name
FROM master
```

тут все отлично, НО я не знаю как добавить к этому запросу еще поля для выборки.

Вот что я примерно имею ввиду:

```
SELECT поле23, поле24 + *запрос указанный выше*
```

Comment: Вы очень странно связываете таблицы и совершенно не ясно, какие поля нужно добавить в выборку.

Comment: ну к примеру любой столбец с другой таблицы. Я не могу понять синтаксис запросов на выборку вместе с UNION

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону join

Comment: Какие поля в итоге хотите получить и по каким условиям хотите сделать выборку?

Comment: Если вы объединяете с помощью UNION, то поля, выбираемые в двух запросах, должны совпадать по типу и количество их должно быть одинаково. Поэтому если хотите связать два селекта, то действительно объединяйте в помощью join.

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, что TS сам не понимает, что хочет сделать... Поскольку речь идёт о самом простом случае, то (по видимому) имеется в виду вот что:

```
SELECT master.name, employee.name FROM master, employee WHERE
master.id == employee.id
```

В таком виде SELECT хотя-бы, имеет очевидный смысл...

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос очень непонятен. Предположительно вот пример

```
    select "любое значение1", "любое значение2", z.name from  
    (SELECT master.name FROM master
    UNION ALL
    SELECT employee.name FROM employee) z
    where z.name = 'Admin'
```

И что подразумевается под "я не знаю как добавить к этому запросу еще поля для выборки" ?